# Change the document root for any domain to its own subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, document-root

I am trying to create an .htaccess file that will change the document root of a domain to a subfolder on my server without actually changing the url to the end user. Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

- `domain1.com` will look for web content in `/domains/domain1.com` but still appear as `domain1.com`.
- `domain2.com` will look for web content in `/domains/domain2.com` but still appear as `domain2.com`.

Every domain will be pointed to the root directory `/` so I am placing the .htaccess file here, `/.htaccess`.

I do not want to have to add every domain I have to the .htaccess file, I would like it to follow this format for every domain that comes its way.

---

I tried learning about .htaccess and create one myself, however, I can't seem a way to this. What I have currently have makes each domain redirect to its subdirectory and gives an error of "too many redirects".

- ie. `domain1.com` redirects the end user to `domain1.com/domains/domain1.com`

This is the contents of the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domains/%1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not bad, try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
# remove www, externally for consistent domains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$
RewriteRule .* http://%1/$0 [NS,L,R=301]
# document root emulation
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .+
RewriteRule ^(?!domains/[^/]+/).* domains/%0/$0 [NS,L]
```